# Bullet point entity is shown as  (box type unknown entity) in the data which have to be captured by Perl program

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

I have an xml file where the data of the bullet point is shown in the form of box entity  which i am unable to capture using Perl program.Can someone help me on this point !!

**Part of Input Data :**

> <p> Adding Basic Requirements: AU sec. 334 suggests procedures for the auditor's consideration, noting that not all of them may be required in every audit.</p>

**Expected output :**

> <p>Adding Basic Requirements: AU sec. 334 suggests procedures for the auditor's consideration, noting that not all of them may be required in every audit.</p>

**Perl Program :**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my $ext = $ARGV[1];
my $inputfile = $filename . "\." . $ext;
my $document = do {
         local $/ = undef;
         open my $fh,'<',$inputfile or die "Couldn't open the file $inputfile:$!";
       <$fh>;
      };

open my $out,">$filename.sgm" or die "Couldn\'t write to the file $filename.sgm:$!"; 

$document =~ s/?/<i>/isg;

print $out $document;
```

**Output :**

Program unable to capture that box type entity and results nothing . No change in the output

Comment: You are confused about something but I can't really figure out exactly what: What do you think `\.` and `\'` do?

Comment: You might want to try `$document =~ s/\P{ascii}+//g` to remove all non-ASCII characters. But that is a very broad brush that may remove text that you want to retain.

Comment: Its not question mark . I have edited and put the exact symbol which is (box entity)

Comment: You made an edit to your question that fixed the problem, so I reverted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My browser shows a box with F0B7 in it, meaning the character is U+F0B7, a [private use character](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html).

If your Perl code file is encoded using UTF-8 and it contains `use utf8;`, you could simply use that character as the regex

```
s/\s*//g
```

But it will be more readable to name it instead.

```
s/\x{F0B7}\s*//g

s/\N{U+F0B7}\s*//g
```

In all cases, the input file will need to be properly decoded.

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: It is not question mark . But it is (box entity) which have to be a bullet point. So how can i capture such unknown entities

Comment: Thanks ikegami for the invalid character literal !!

Comment: Nit: U+FFFD is the replacement character used for invalid input. What you have is U+F0B7, a valid character available for [private use](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html).